# Mount S3 bucket to ec2 instance using S3FS

Tags: amazon-s3, mount, s3fs

When running the following mount command I get a unable to access MOUNTPOINT url=https://s3-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com: no such file or directory. I get the same error when using endpoint=us-gov-west-1 instead of url

```
s3fs your_bucketname -o use_cache=/tmp -o allow_other -o uid=1001 -o mp_umask=002 -o multireq_max=5-o url=https://s3-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com  /mys3bucket
```

Comment: Typo: `-o multireq_max=5-o url` is missing a space between `=5` and the next `-o`, causing everything following that point to be misinterpreted.

Comment: This was it. Thanks!